# How to get a value of a custom sql srv variable or a result set when calling procedure in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

how can an SQL variable be declared to be used in a procedure statement and then its value be returned to PHP? If I declare it in a separate query before the execution of a procedure, I get the following error:

> `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Must declare the table variable "@Id".`

When I use the DB::unprepared() method to execute all queries in the same statement, the above error goes away, but I don't get a result back. I need to get the @ReturnError and @Id so I can use them in my PHP code.

This is the procedure call

```
    DECLARE @Id int
    DECLARE @ReturnError int

    exec dbo.[CRMHL_Subject.Insert] @Id           = @Id output, 
                                    @Subject      = 'John Doe', 
                                    @Name         = 'John Doe', 
                                    @Address      = '',
                                    @Post         = '', 
                                    @VATCode      = '', 
                                    @RegNo        = '',
                                    @Rebate       = 0,
                                    @PriceRate    = 0,
                                    @Currency     = '', 
                                    @Delivery     = '', 
                                    @PayMethod    = '',
                                    @WayOfSale    = '',
                                    @GSM          = '', 
                                    @Phone        = '', 
                                    @eMail        = '',
                                    @ReturnError  = @ReturnError output
```

Comment: Do not use store procedures when using laravel, laravel takes care of logic, not your DB.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but normally your driver passes through parameters, you don't declare them in the query. You would need to declare it client-side as an output parameter